# one fragment crashes after .add while the other does not

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to get fragments working but the behavior isn't consistent and it is difficult to debug.  I've created two fragments with xml files and class files.  As far as I can tell, the two frags are implemented in exactly the same manner.

When I .add "BlankFragment _frag1" in the MainActivity, it runs.  When I .add BlankFragment2 _frag2, it crashes when the code exits the MainActivity.onCreate method.

I had this issue in a more complex app, so I stripped off all the extraneous stuff and implemented it with the simplest app I could....still happens.

I have attached the .java files and .xml files below.  I would include a zip of the whole project, but I don't see an attach file dialog.  I can send the project via email if someone shoots me a request at darrylctx@gmail.com.

In the MainActivity.onCreate method, there are two lines:

```
    _ft.add(R.id.container, _frag1);
    _ft.add(R.id.container, _frag2);
```

If I comment out _ft.add(R.id.container, _frag2); 
and uncomment //_ft.add(R.id.container, _frag1);  then it runs fine.
That is, _frag1 runs fine.

If I comment out _ft.add(R.id.container, _frag1);
and uncomment _ft.add(R.id.container, _frag2);  it crashes on exit from the onCreate method.  That is, _frag2 does not run.

As far as I can tell, there is not difference between the implementations of frag1 and frag2, but I must be missing something.

```
// MainActivity.java ------------------------------------------------------------


 package com.example.dcornish.TestFrag;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    //import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        BlankFragment _frag1 = new BlankFragment();
        BlankFragment2 _frag2 = new BlankFragment2();
        FragmentManager _fm;
        FragmentTransaction _ft;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            // get the viewgroup for this activity
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);

            //Fragment Help:  add fragment to main activity
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new BlankFragment()).commit();
                _fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                _ft = _fm.beginTransaction();
                // comment out one or the other of the _ft.add methods below to change fragments
                //_ft.add(R.id.container, _frag1);
                _ft.add(R.id.container, _frag2);
                _ft.commit();
            }

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }

        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Wheeee!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

//  BlankFragment.java ----------------------------------------

```
package com.example.dcornish.TestFrag;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements Button.OnClickListener{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private Button mButton; //Add at the top of the fragment

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        View view = null;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    //Fragment Help:  Have to figure out what mListener.onFragmentInteraction(null) does
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Nothing here yet
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(null);
    }
}
```

// BlankFragment2.java  --------------------------------------------------

```
package com.example.dcornish.TestFrag;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link BlankFragment2.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragment2#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragment2 extends Fragment implements Button.OnClickListener{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private Button _button;

    public BlankFragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment2.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment2 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment2 fragment = new BlankFragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = null;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_2, container, false);
        _button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.whee_button);
        _button.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        //Nothing here yet
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(null);
    }
}
```

// activity_main.xml -----------------------------------------------------

```
<!--  fragment instructions: android:id = "@+id/container" -->
<!--  give id to the mainActivity layout so it can be referenced as container for fragments -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.dcornish.TestFrag.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




  // content_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.dcornish.TestFrag.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

// fragment_blank.xml---------------------------------------------------

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dcornish.TestFrag.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Whee"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

// fragment_blank_2.xml -------------------------------------------------

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment2">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TrajMgr"
        android:id="@+id/whee_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

// menu_main.xml -----------------------------------------------------------

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.dcornish.TestFrag.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnu_edit_profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Edit Profile"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnu_load_profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Load Profile"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnu_save_profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Save Profile"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnu_help"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Help"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnu_dash1"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="------------"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnu_exit"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Exit"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnu_test"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Test"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please add your stacktrace error too

Comment: What is the crash you are getting and in what file?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might see what is causing the crash. When you add `BlankFragment2` you have to also implement it's listener `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

It should look like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, BlankFragment2.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    BlankFragment _frag1 = new BlankFragment();
    BlankFragment2 _frag2 = new BlankFragment2();
    FragmentManager _fm;
    FragmentTransaction _ft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // get the viewgroup for this activity
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        //Fragment Help:  add fragment to main activity
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new BlankFragment()).commit();
            _fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            _ft = _fm.beginTransaction();
            // comment out one or the other of the _ft.add methods below to change fragments
//            _ft.add(R.id.container, _frag1);
            _ft.add(R.id.container, _frag2);
            _ft.commit();
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```